# Quotient group-cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Compute the factor group $(\mathbb{Z_6}\times \mathbb{Z_4})/\langle(3,2)\rangle$ and   $\langle(3,2)\rangle=\{(0,0), (3,2)\}$.
Here is what I have so far. I know I have 12 left cosets which are.
$$(1,0)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle =\{(1,0),(4,2)\}$$
$$(2,0)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle=\{(2,0),(5,2)\}$$
$$(3,0)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle=\{(3,0),(0,2)\}$$
$$(4,0)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle =\{(4,0),(1,2)\}$$
$$(5,0)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle =\{(5,0),(2,2)\}$$
$$(0,1)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle =\{(0,1),(3,3)\}$$
$$(0,3)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle =\{(0,3),(3,1)\}$$
$$(1,1)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle =\{(1,1),(4,3)\}$$
$$(1,3)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle =\{(1,3),(4,1)\}$$
$$(2,1)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle =\{(2,1),(5,3)\}$$
$$(2,3)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle =\{(2,3),(5,1)\}$$
Now I have to find a group that this is isomorphic to which I am having trouble with. I think its isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ but I can't seem to find a generator for the cossets. Thanks

Comment: I've changed things like $<(3,2)>$ to $\langle(3,2)\rangle$ in the first several instances.  I'll leave it to others to clean up the rest of this.  TeX and LaTeX were created for a purpose.  The purpose was NOT to enable people to feel that they're restricted to the characters on a typewriter keyboard.

Comment: oh ok i changed it.

Comment: I got it I think it was $(2,1)+ \langle(3,2)\rangle$ that has order 12.

Answer (score 0):

The element $(2,1)+\langle(3,2)\rangle$ is indeed of order 12, precisely because $(2,1)$ is of order 12 in $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$, and the subgroup in $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ generated by $(2,1)$ does not contain $(3,2)$. This can be seen by observing that the 3 in the left entry of $(3,2)$ cannot be generated by the 2 in the left entry of $(2,1)$.